# Why is being yourself so highly valued among existentialist philosophers?

Tags: existentialism, identity

From the Disney movie *Wreck-it-Ralph*:

> I'm bad, and that's good. I will never be good, and that's not bad. There's no one I'd rather be than me.

Is this sentiment wise? Is it truly good to be whoever you are, with whatever temperaments and interior disposition Providence has assigned to you? Or is this sour grapes ("I can't be like Einstein/J-sus/Buddha... so it must not really be that desirable") or fatalism ("The Universe does not allow us the ability to be who we choose, so we must be grateful for whoever we are.")?

Comment: Most existentialist philosophers were atheists. They believed neither in Providence nor in immutable dispositions, but rather in self-making, and that is what "being yourself" referred to. *Make* yourself, rather than be made by dispositions, external influences and other eventualities, and own it. Is it "truly good"? In the absence of Providence or platonic forms to dictate such things the question is vacuous. That is *their* standard of goodness. Of course, from the point of view of Christian ethics it might be seen as hubris, although, with revisions, there was Christian existentialism too.

Comment: @Conifold "Make yourself, rather than be made by dispositions, external influences and other eventualities, and own it." This is not logically possible, unless the existentialist philosophers had access to alien technology or magic powers to rewire their brains.

Comment: It is certainly possible logically, whether it is possible physically and biologically, even without technology, is still an open question, free will and so on. They believed that biology isn't destiny, as do many others.

Comment: "*Be yourself. Everyone else is already taken.*"

Comment: @ScottRowe That sounds like fatalism.

Comment: Being oneself is highly valued, probably because it is not optional, so we might as well make the most of it. What would you gain by *not* making the most of your once lifetime opportunity?

Comment: @ScottRowe Because it feels too much like the Protestant work ethic.

Comment: Try Nonduality instead? There is always the poem "The Summer Day" by Mary Oliver.

Comment: I'd say the message from Wreck-It-Ralph is that being yourself is not the same as accepting some kind of label on your forehead as an unchangeable given. Especially if it has been applied by the environment/society. That includes this "evil" guys support group.

Comment: @kutschkem You offer good analysis.

Comment: @ScottRowe What is "Nonduality" and what do you mean by it?

Comment: Nonduality means not seeing yourself as separate from everything that is. There is some current research being done by The Center for the Study of Non-Symbolic Consciousness at: nonsymbolic.org